# How do I stop Heroku from changing the location header and causing 401 with my Spring boot OAuth2 service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, oauth-2.0

I have a spring boot oauth2 service working locally.  But when I deploy this to Heroku it fails with a 401.

So on my local system I go to the UI and I have no valid JWT so it does a redirect to:

```
localhost:8080/api/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=clienteagleeye&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=webClient
```

The spring gateway routes to my auth service, `localhost:8066/auth/login`.  I login with valid username/password and it routes to `localhost:8066/auth/validate`, which gives this response header:

```
Location: localhost:8066/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=clienteagleeye&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=webClient
```

It redirects to:

```
localhost:8066/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=clienteagleeye&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=webClient
```

...and the response header location on that call is: `localhost:4200#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.etc...`

It routes back to the UI and I have the access token.  Everything works as expected.

I do this in Heroku I get to this auth/validate step `abc-authserver.herokuapp.com/auth/validate`, and the response header location is `Location: abc-authserver.herokuapp.com/auth/`.

I am expecting it to be:

```
abc-authserver.herokuapp.com/auth/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=clienteagleeye&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%dummyui&scope=webClient
```

but its not so it routes to `abc-authserver.herokuapp.com/auth/` and I get a 401.

**Why is Heroku dropping my response_type, client_id, scope and redirect_uri information? Why is it changing the Location in the response header when I am validating?**  The logs show that my username and password are correct and I have the information. It just has no idea where to go.

This is my resourceConfig in the authservice...

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors().and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**", "/auth/**", "/oauth/**", "/login", "/validate").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/validate")
            .and()
            .logout().and().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

I need to figure out how to not lose the redirect information.  I can provide any additional information needed. I am wasting tons of time trying to figure this out.  I would appreciate any input. Thanks.

Comment: try it ("/api/**", "**/auth/**", "**/oauth/**", "/login", "/validate")

Comment: use ** prefix before endpoint

Comment: no luck on the endpoint modifications. so it kinda works now I added a successHandler, I implemented AuthenticationSuccessHandler and I recreate the authorize URL and do redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, redirectUrl) ... this appears to work, just not sure how desirable this is.